# SQL percentage SUM different than 100

Tags: mysql, sql, percentage

I'm using this query to grab the usage percentage of stickers (pdo):

```
SELECT
id_sticker,
CAST((COUNT(*) / :stickers_count * 100) AS UNSIGNED) as percentage
FROM user_sticker AS sticker_total
WHERE id_user_to = :id_user
GROUP BY id_sticker
ORDER BY percentage DESC
```

This is the final result:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id_sticker": 2,
            "percentage": 28.5714285714
        },
        {
            "id_sticker": 1,
            "percentage": 14.2857142857
        },
        {
            "id_sticker": 3,
            "percentage": 14.2857142857
        },
        {
            "id_sticker": 5,
            "percentage": 14.2857142857
        },
        {
            "id_sticker": 6,
            "percentage": 14.2857142857
        },
        {
            "id_sticker": 7,
            "percentage": 14.2857142857
        }
    ]
}
```

The total sum of the percentages is 99.9999999999 ... it should be 100 (that is triggering an error with the piechart component i'm using). Any ideas? Thanks!

**SOLUTION**

I ended adding this php fix after grabbing the data:

```
        $dif = 100;
        foreach($result as $item) {
            $dif = $dif - $item['percentage'];
        }
        if($dif > 0) {
            $result[0]['percentage'] += $dif;
        } elseif($dif < 0) {
            $result[count($result)-1]['percentage'] += $dif;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a rounding error. If you need it to add up to 100, just round the values to 1 or 2 decimal places (that should be enough for a pie chart) and recalculate the last one as `100 - sum(1..(n-1))` (that's pseudocode, by the way).

Answer (score 1):

You can't seriously be expecting perfect [precision](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) with floating arithmetic, can you?